# NPoco and PostgreSQL: PostgresException: 53300: sorry, too many clients already

Tags: postgresql, npoco

**NPoco and PostgreSQL: PostgresException: 53300: sorry, too many clients already**

I'm getting this error when I browse my own website allverse.co for a while. Here's the project: https://github.com/claysmith/allverse

and typical NPoco connection code in each Controller...

```
    private IDatabase _db = new Database(new NpgsqlConnection(Startup.Configuration["PostgresConn"]), DatabaseType.PostgreSQL, NpgsqlFactory.Instance); 

    private IDatabase GetDB()
    {
        return _db; 
    }

    public SomeFunc()
    {
        using(IDatabase db = GetDB())
        {
            try
            {
                article.id = (long)db.Insert(article); 
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                string m = ex.Message;
                string im = ex.InnerException.ToString(); 
            }
        }
     }
```

Do I need to increase my postgresql connections or am I not closing connections somewhere? Thanks.

Comment: yes you got to `max_connections`, either increase them or reduce the amount. you code looks java? java has connection pooler...

Comment: @VaoTsun Actully C# on .NET Core... how would I reduce the amount of connections? I am new at this. Thanks.

Comment: you can close several idle for too long connections with `pg_terminate_backend(pid)`. but first go through your code to find why you have so many connections kept.