# postgres listen notification generates error - 53300: sorry, too many clients already

Tags: c#, notifications, postgresql-9.1, listen

During listen notification from postgres trigger, we encounter Error 53300: sorry, too many clients already. Please suggest, if we can resolve it somehow. On closing connection object it stops sending notification. we are using Signal R for receiving notifications.

```
public async Task BrokerConfig()
{
    var con = new NpgsqlConnection("host=x.x.x.x;Port=5432;Database=Ticket;User Id=someid;Password=pwd;Connection Idle Lifetime=0;Timeout=0;;Command Timeout=0;");

    con.Notification += LogNotificationHelper;
    con.Open();
    using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "LISTEN notifytickets;";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    
        // Waiting for Event
        con.WaitAsync();
    
}

static void LogNotificationHelper(object sender, NpgsqlNotificationEventArgs e)
 {
   ///further code to read notification values..
 }
```

Comment: Check this out it seems to be similar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43725343/npoco-and-postgresql-postgresexception-53300-sorry-too-many-clients-already

Comment: not really, we are using notification, and for that we need to keep my connection open until the notification raised. But if we close our connection notification no longer received.

Comment: One solution would be to not open that many connections to your database. Another thing that could alleviate this is KeepAlive https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html#timeouts-and-keepalive

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the max number of allowed connection in the postgres config

```
*max_connections (integer)*

Determines the maximum number of concurrent connections to the database server. The default is typically 100 connections, but might be less if your kernel settings will not support it (as determined during initdb). This parameter can only be set at server start.

When running a standby server, you must set this parameter to the same or higher value than on the master server. Otherwise, queries will not be allowed in the standby server.
```

See [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/runtime-config-connection.html)